# Django Multiple response of queryset

Tags: python, django

In the search, I am trying to search the database through title using this code

```
product_title =  request.GET.get('txtSearch')
status = product.objects.filter(title__icontains=product_title)
```

And there is another column called product_Subcategory how to get that column using this data?

OR

How to get complete row of this title I have searched?

when I try to print status I got this queryset

<QuerySet [<product: OnePlus 7T Pro (Haze Blue, 8GB RAM, Fluid AMOLED Display, 256GB Storage, 4085mAH Battery)>]>

In which there is no product_Subcategory...if anyone can help...Thanks.

Comment: Please study Django a lot more.  Go through the tutorial

Comment: They `QuerySet` repr does not always include all columns. I find it rarely does. Did you try `print(status.subcategory)`? If you need to be assured that all your columns are there, you can `from django.forms import model_to_dict`, convert your row into a dict, and print that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In querysets, objects are presented like this. It contains all the attributes values. You can get the subcategory value like this

```
for product in status:

    subcategory = product.subcategory
```

or try `.values()`. It will return list of dictionaries

```
status = product.objects.filter(title__icontains=product_title).values()
```

Comment: .values() function doesn't work for me but your first suggestion work as a charm...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get all the values for Product, Please use "values", Note that What you did earlier was getting you the Queryset of all 'Product' objects that matched the criteria, but since you just need the values, you can use the following. The result will be a list of dictionaries.
Like so,

```
status = product.objects.filter(title__icontains=product_title).values()
```

If you just want a specific column value, you can mention that with the 'values' attribute.
Like so,

```
subcategory = 
product.objects.filter(title__icontains=product_title).values('subcategory')
```

Again this will be a dictionary like [{subcategory:'a'},{subcategory:'b'}]

If you just want the list of subcategories you can try

```
subcategory_list = list(
product.objects.filter(title__icontains=product_title).values_list('subcategory',flat=True))
```

The result will be ['a','b']